# Yum Fails When Installing PHP

Tags: linux, php, yum

I tried to install PHP with yum and I got a message like:

```
bash-3.2# yum install php
```

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: mirrors.tummy.com
 * updates: mirror.anl.gov
 * base: www.cyberuse.com
 * addons: mirror.raystedman.net
 * extras: www.cyberuse.com
Setting up Install Process
Parsing package install arguments
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php.x86_64 0:5.1.6-23.2.el5_3 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php-cli = 5.1.6-23.2.el5_3 for package: php
--> Processing Dependency: httpd-mmn = 20051115 for package: php
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.1.6-23.2.el5_3 for package: php
--> Processing Dependency: file >= 4.0 for package: php
--> Processing Dependency: libaspell.so.15()(64bit) for package: php
--> Processing Dependency: libgmp.so.3()(64bit) for package: php
--> Processing Dependency: libcurl.so.3()(64bit) for package: php
--> Processing Dependency: libpspell.so.15()(64bit) for package: php
--> Processing Dependency: libidn.so.11()(64bit) for package: php
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-cli.x86_64 0:5.1.6-23.2.el5_3 set to be updated
---> Package httpd.x86_64 0:2.2.3-22.el5.centos.1 set to be updated
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/yum", line 29, in ?
    yummain.user_main(sys.argv[1:], exit_code=True)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 229, in user_main
    errcode = main(args)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 145, in main
    (result, resultmsgs) = base.buildTransaction()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/**init**.py", line 647, in buildTransaction
    (rescode, restring) = self.resolveDeps()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/depsolve.py", line 696, in resolveDeps
    CheckDeps, checkinstalls, checkremoves, missing = self._resolveRequires(errors)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/depsolve.py", line 779, in _resolveRequires
    thisneeds = self._checkInstall(txmbr)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/depsolve.py", line 851, in _checkInstall
    provs = self.tsInfo.getProvides(*req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/transactioninfo.py", line 432, in getProvides
    result.update(self.getNewProvides(name, flag, version))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/transactioninfo.py", line 414, in getNewProvides
    for pkg, hits in self.pkgSack.getProvides(name, flag, version).iteritems():
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/packageSack.py", line 300, in getProvides
    return self._computeAggregateDictResult("getProvides", name, flags, version)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/packageSack.py", line 470, in _computeAggregateDictResult
    sackResult = apply(method, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/sqlitesack.py", line 861, in getProvides
    return self._search("provides", name, flags, version)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/sqlitesack.py", line 43, in newFunc
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/sqlitesack.py", line 837, in _search
    for pkg in self.searchFiles(name, strict=True):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/sqlitesack.py", line 43, in newFunc
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/sqlitesack.py", line 586, in searchFiles
    self._sql_pkgKey2po(rep, cur, pkgs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/sqlitesack.py", line 470, in _sql_pkgKey2po
    pkg = self._packageByKey(repo, ob['pkgKey'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/sqlitesack.py", line 413, in _packageByKey
    po = self.pc(repo, cur.fetchone())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/sqlitesack.py", line 68, in **init**
    self._read_db_obj(db_obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/sqlitesack.py", line 94, in _read_db_obj
    setattr(self, item, _share_data(db_obj[item]))
TypeError: unsubscriptable object

Comment: Can you please edit and quote the yum output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Post output on [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)

Try "yum clean all" like the first poster says.

Comment: Not working for me, for some reason. Neither what the other people suggested here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `yum clean all` first and see if that solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try `#yum update yum && yum update`.

Can you install other packages?